# php xpath on XML

Tags: php, xml, xpath

How can I achieve this:

```
<root>
<gallery name="First">
 <picture active="1" detail="not shown"/>
 <picture active="1" detail="not shown"/>
 <picture active="0" detail="not shown"/>
</gallery>
<gallery name="Second">
 <picture active="0" detail="not shown"/>
 <picture active="1" detail="SHOW THIS ONE"/>
 <picture active="1" detail="AND SHOW THIS ONE" />
</gallery>
</root>
```

I'm trying:

```
$myArray = $objXML->xpath('gallery[@name="Second"]/picture[@active=1]');
```

How can I change it to get the desired output?
Thanks, Andy

Comment: why did you change from DOM in your last question to SimpleXml now?

Comment: I was using DOM for adding and deleting nodes because I'd read that it was much easier than with SimpleXML, I am using SimpleXML for displaying and editing the XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your XPath is wrong. Either use

```
/root/gallery[@name="Second"]/picture[@active=1]
```

to match this node constellation from the root node only or

```
//gallery[@name="Second"]/picture[@active=1]
```

to match this node constellation anywhere in the document (slower)

Full working examples:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('NewFile.xml'); // containing your XML
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$pictures = $xp->query('/root/gallery[@name="Second"]/picture[@active=1]');
foreach ($pictures as $picture) {
    echo $dom->saveXml($picture), PHP_EOL;
}
```

gives

```
<picture active="1" detail="SHOW THIS ONE"/>
<picture active="1" detail="AND SHOW THIS ONE"/>
```

and

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement('NewFile.xml', NULL, TRUE);
$pictures = $sxe->xpath('/root/gallery[@name="Second"]/picture[@active=1]');
foreach ($pictures as $picture) {
    echo $picture['detail'], PHP_EOL;
}
```

gives

```
SHOW THIS ONE 
AND SHOW THIS ONE
```

Comment: they don't work for me, are you allowed to query for more than one thing in xpath?

Comment: @andy see update. "don't work for me" is not a proper error description. please clarify your issues with it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't have time to properly check it on Friday. Now I've just had another look and realised I'd changed my XML file and that was why it wasn't working. The xpath stuff was fine all along!! Thanks for your help, Andy