# why I can't get first child value for a XML file in php

Tags: php, xml

I used an `XMLHttpRequest` object to retrieve data from a PHP response.

Then, I created an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persons>
    <person>
        <name>Ce</name>
        <gender>male</gender>
        <age>24</age>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Lin</name>
        <gender>female</gender>
        <age>25</age>
    </person>
</persons>
```

In the PHP file, I load the XML file and try to echo tag values of "name."

```
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$dom -> load("test.xml");
$persons = $dom -> getElementsByTagName("person");
foreach($persons as $person){
    echo $person -> childNodes -> item(0) -> nodeValue;
}
```

But the `nodeValue` returned is `null`. However, when I change to `item(1)`, the name tag values can be displayed. Why?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827871/php-domdocument-get-node-value-where-attribute-value-is)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using DOM you need to get the right element to pick up the name, child nodes include all sorts of things including whitespace.  The node 0 your trying to use is null because of this.  So for DOM...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$dom -> load("test.xml");
$persons = $dom -> getElementsByTagName("person");
foreach($persons as $person){
   $name = $person->getElementsByTagName("name");
   echo $name->item(0)->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
}
```

If your requirements are as simple as this, you could alternatively use SimpleXML...

```
$sxml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
foreach ( $sxml->person as $person )    {
    echo $person->name.PHP_EOL;
}
```

This allows you to access elements as though they are object properties and as you can see `->person` equates to accessing `<person>`.

Comment: In your code, seems like after get nodelist of person, still need to get a nodelist of name, instead of directly use childNodes property?

Comment: The problem with childNodes in DOM is that they are split down to each element.  Blindly using `->childNodes->item(1)` could pick up any element, if the XML changed it could pick up another field.  Specifically fetching the `name` element avoids this risk.

Answer (score 0):

Change code to

```
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$dom -> load("test.xml");
$persons = $dom -> getElementsByTagName("persons");
foreach($persons as $person){
echo  $person->childNodes[1]->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: I tried, didn't work. It's clear that there is only one tag of persons which is root, its first child is tag of person, not name

Answer (score 0):

Anything in a DOM is a node, include texts and text with only whitespaces. So the first child of the `person` element node is a text node that contains the linebreak and indent before the `name` element node.

Here is a property that removes any whitespace node at parse time:

```
$document = new DOMDocument("1.0");
// do not preserve whitespace only text nodes
$document->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$document->load("test.xml");
$persons = $document->getElementsByTagName("person");
foreach ($persons as $person) {
    echo $person->firstChild->textContent;
}
```

However typically a better way is to use Xpath expressions.

```
$document = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$document->load("test.xml");
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document)
$persons = $xpath->evaluate("/persons/person");
foreach ($persons as $person) {
    echo $xpath->evaluate("string(name)", $person);
}
```

`string(name)` fetches the child element node `name` (position is not relevant) and casts it into a string. If here is no `name` element it will return an empty string.